# get matlab standalone application output from php

Tags: php, matlab, cmd, exe

I have converted my .m file into a standalone application with the aid of deploytool.

Now, I want to run my application and get the outputs using PHP.
I can run my application on cmd. And it will return the outputs and print.
But I can not get the outputs from PHP.

this is the main file of my standalone application:

```
function [onsets,pitch,endpoint] =  matxtwavtomidi( input_args )

input=strsplit(input_args);
[s wavFs] = audioread(input{1});
[onsets,pitch,endpoint]=txtwavtomidi(s);

end
```

this is the result I get from cmd:

```
C:\Users\user> START /WAIT D:/java/matlab/matxtwavtomidi.exe D:/song.wav

onsets =
    1.7183
    1.7183
    2.3220
    2.3220

pitch =
    60
    72
    62
    74

endpoint =
    1.8576
    1.9040
    3.0650
    2.4149
```

this is my PHP:

```
<?php
$stringcmd= "START /WAIT D:/java/matlab/matxtwavtomidi.exe ";
$stringwav = "D:/song.wav";

exec($stringcmd.$stringwav, $output, $return_var);

echo $stringcmd.$stringwav;
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);

?>
```

this is the result from php:

```
START /WAIT D:/java/matlab/matxtwavtomidi.exe D:/song.wav
array(0) { }
int(0)
```

Everytime when i run the application on cmd, it will always show the application's icon picture in the middle of the screen for 2 seconds and then disappear.

And when I run my PHP, it did show the icon picture,so I think it did run the application.
And there are no error in php_error_log and apache error_log.

My problem is,why can't my PHP get the outputs of the application from cmd?
And how to solve this problem?

(Sorry for my poor English..)

Answer (score 0):

One good solution is to write your data from matlab to a .txt file and then read that file from your server side..
Hope it helps